Can ADF Web Activity is used to make Rest API call and Bring large size data
Hello All I am new to ADF Activity and I need your opinion and help if i am doing right by design by using Web Activity to bring large size of data into my Data target. I tried using Web Activity In my ADF Pipeline to make REST API call and bring the data from remote web source system to target Snowflake Datawarehouse.
The remote source has data in terms of GB, when i first executed this web-activity i was able to get the data for top 10 rows by using top parameter in Web URL but when i switched my pipeline to other environment I started getting error message as "The length of execution output is over limit (around 4MB currently)".
Not sure i am using right ADF activity to get the data from remote system, or is there is any alternate activity available in ADF to make REST API call and bring large size of data into my target system.
Appreciate your help here.

APIs are not a mechanism usually employed to move large volumes of data. Direct access to the underlying datastore would normally be much more performant

Web activity, can only bring 4MB of data. So its not right choice in this case.

Consider using copy activity and under source tab, use REST type
dataset. This helps you to load data from REST API to target.

